# Numbered page navigation script not working for search label and query results

Tags: javascript, blogger

I am working on a blog with custom template which includes this **numbered page navigation script** below. Script is working in all pages except search results for queries and labels!!! I tried some changes but as I am not a javascript expert and I couldn't make it work... So, any kind of help would be really appreciated!!!

```
var pageCount = 9;
var displayPageNum = 3;
var upPageWord = "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>";
var downPageWord = "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>";

function showpageCount(x) {
    var C = home_page_url;
    var E = new Array();
    var y = 1;
    var H = 1;
    var v = 0;
    var p = 0;
    var G = 0;
    var F = "";
    var J = "";
    var w = "";
    for (var z = 0, A; A = x.feed.entry[z]; z++) {
        var u = A.published.$t.substring(0, 19) + A.published.$t.substring(23, 29);
        timestamp = encodeURIComponent(u);
        var i = A.title.$t;
        if (i != "") {
            if (v == 0 || (v % pageCount == (pageCount - 1))) {
                if (C.indexOf(timestamp) != -1) {
                    y = H
                }
                if (i != "") {
                    H++
                }
                E[E.length] = "/search?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + pageCount
            }
        }
        v++
    }
    for (var D = 0; D < E.length; D++) {
        if (D >= (y - displayPageNum - 1) && D < (y + displayPageNum)) {
            if (p == 0 && D == y - 2) {
                if (y == 2) {
                    J = '<span class="showpage"><a href="/">' + upPageWord + "</a></span>"
                } else {
                    J = '<span class="showpage"><a href="' + E[D] + '">' + upPageWord + "</a></span>"
                }
                p++
            }
            if (D == (y - 1)) {
                F += '<span class="showpagePoint">' + y + "</span>"
            } else {
                if (D == 0) {
                    F += '<span class="showpageNum"><a href="/">1</a></span>'
                } else {
                    F += '<span class="showpageNum"><a href="' + E[D] + '">' + (D + 1) + "</a></span>"
                }
            }
            if (G == 0 && D == y) {
                w = '<span class="showpage"> <a href="' + E[D] + '">' + downPageWord + "</a></span>";
                G++
            }
        }
    }
    if (y > 1) {
        F = "" + J + " " + F + " "
    }
    F = '<div class="showpageArea">' + F;
    if (y < (H - 1)) {
        F += w
    }
    if (H == 1) {
        H++
    }
    F += "</div>";
    var I = document.getElementsByName("pageArea");
    var B = document.getElementById("blog-pager");
    if (H <= 2) {
        F = ""
    }
    for (var D = 0; D < I.length; D++) {
        I[D].innerHTML = F
    }
    if (I && I.length > 0) {
        F = ""
    }
    if (B) {
        B.innerHTML = F
    }
}

function showpageCount2(A) {
    var F = home_page_url;
    var G = new Array();
    var J = F.indexOf("/search/label/") != -1;
    var M = J ? F.substr(F.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, F.length) : "";
    M = M.indexOf("?") != -1 ? M.substr(0, M.indexOf("?")) : M;
    var B = 1;
    var L = 1;
    var y = 0;
    var p = 0;
    var K = 0;
    var I = "";
    var P = "";
    var z = "";
    var N = '<span class="showpageNum"><a href="/search/label/' + M + "?&max-results=" + pageCount + '">';
    var F = home_page_url;
    for (var C = 0, D; D = A.feed.entry[C]; C++) {
        var x = D.published.$t.substring(0, 19) + D.published.$t.substring(23, 29);
        timestamp = encodeURIComponent(x);
        var i = D.title.$t;
        if (i != "") {
            if (y == 0 || (y % pageCount == (pageCount - 1))) {
                if (F.indexOf(timestamp) != -1) {
                    B = L
                }
                if (i != "") {
                    L++
                }
                G[G.length] = "/search/label/" + M + "?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + pageCount
            }
        }
        y++
    }
    for (var H = 0; H < G.length; H++) {
        if (H >= (B - displayPageNum - 1) && H < (B + displayPageNum)) {
            if (p == 0 && H == B - 2) {
                if (B == 2) {
                    P = N + upPageWord + "</a></span>"
                } else {
                    P = '<span class="showpage"><a href="' + G[H] + '">' + upPageWord + "</a></span>"
                }
                p++
            }
            if (H == (B - 1)) {
                I += '<span class="showpagePoint">' + B + "</span>"
            } else {
                if (H == 0) {
                    I = N + "1</a></span>"
                } else {
                    I += '<span class="showpageNum"><a href="' + G[H] + '">' + (H + 1) + "</a></span>"
                }
            }
            if (K == 0 && H == B) {
                z = '<span class="showpage"> <a href="' + G[H] + '">' + downPageWord + "</a></span>";
                K++
            }
        }
    }
    if (B > 1) {
        if (!J) {
            I = "" + P + " " + I + " "
        } else {
            I = "" + P + " " + I + " "
        }
    }
    I = '<div class="showpageArea">' + I;
    if (B < (L - 1)) {
        I += z
    }
    if (L == 1) {
        L++
    }
    I += "</div>";
    var O = document.getElementsByName("pageArea");
    var E = document.getElementById("blog-pager");
    if (L <= 2) {
        I = ""
    }
    for (var H = 0; H < O.length; H++) {
        O[H].innerHTML = I
    }
    if (O && O.length > 0) {
        I = ""
    }
    if (E) {
        E.innerHTML = I
    }
}
var home_page_url = location.href;
var thisUrl = home_page_url;
if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") != -1) {
    if (thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max") != -1) {
        var lblname1 = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max"))
    } else {
        var lblname1 = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?&max"))
    }
}
var home_page = "/";
if (thisUrl.indexOf("?q=") == -1) {
    if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") == -1) {
        document.write('<script src="' + home_page + 'feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=showpageCount&max-results=99999" ><\/script>')
    } else {
        document.write('<script src="' + home_page + "feeds/posts/full/-/" + lblname1 + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=showpageCount2&max-results=99999" ><\/script>')
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I couldn't make it work". Do you get any erros? What's the correct and the wrong behaviour? Please provide more details to your question

Comment: Page navigation not shows up in search results for queries and labels as I said!!!

Answer (score -1):

We are currently facing the same problem. The pagination links are good for even pages, but not for off pages. The whole script seems quite buggy, but only for 'search keywords'. Will post results if we achieve any progress.

Comment: This might be better suited as a comment rather than an answer